# Inductive predicates for a fixed tuple parameter

Tags: isabelle

let's assume we have some predicate

```
definition someP :: "('a × 'a) ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
```

and an `inductive` over it

```
inductive my_inductive :: "('a × 'a) ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
 for "a_b" where
 basecase: "fst a_b = a ⟹ my_inductive a_b a" |
 stepcase: "someP a_b x y ⟹ my_inductive a_b x ⟹ my_inductive a_b y"
```

The inductive is fixed for the first parameter "a_b". "a_b" is a tuple which leads to somewhat ugly syntax. Unfortunately isabelle does not allow me writing something like `for "(a,b)"`.

How can I create nicer introduction and induction rules for this inductive predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define a new set of introduction rules `my_inductive_intros` with a more beautiful basecase and the default stepcase

```
lemma my_inductive_intro_1: "my_inductive (a, b) a"
  by (simp add: my_inductive.basecase)
lemmas my_inductive_intros = my_inductive_intro_1 my_inductive.stepcase
```

We can write our own beautiful induction rule

```
lemma my_inductive_tuple_induct[consumes 1, case_names "basecase" "stepcase", induct pred: my_inductive]: 
 "my_inductive (a, b) x ⟹ 
 (P a) ⟹ (⋀x y. someP (a, b) x y ⟹ my_inductive (a, b) x ⟹ P x ⟹ P y) ⟹ P x"
 apply(rule my_inductive.induct[of "(a,b)"])
 apply(simp_all)
 done
```

`consumes 1` tells isabelle to consume the first parameter. Let's illustrate this by an example:

```
lemma "my_inductive (a,b) c ⟹ P a b c"
  proof(induction rule: my_inductive_tuple_induct)
```

Without `[consumes 1]` this is the proof state:

1. my_inductive (?a, ?b) (my_inductive (a, b) c ⟶ P a b c)
2. ?a
3. ⋀x y. someP (?a, ?b) x y ⟹ my_inductive (?a, ?b) x ⟹ x ⟹ y

With `[consumes 1]`, we get the desired proof state:

1. P a b a
2. ⋀x y. someP (a, b) x y ⟹ my_inductive (a, b) x ⟹ P a b x ⟹ P a b y

`case_names` sets up the case names for an isar proof. The above proof can thus start with `case basecase`.

`induct pred` tells that we are declaring an induction rule. In certain cases, just writing `proof(induction)` might now be sufficient that isabelle figures out by itself to use our new fancy induction rule.

The following example demonstrates the setup

```
lemma
  assumes "my_inductive (a,b) c" shows "P a b c"
  using assms
proof (induction)
case basecase thus ?case using my_inductive_intros sorry
case (stepcase x y) thus ?case using my_inductive_intros sorry
qed
```

Comment: The induct attribute automatically sets "consumes 1" for `pred:`icate rules, so the consumes attribute can be dropped. Note also that the order of the attributes is relevant. (If you had written `[induct ..., case_names ...]` the rule would not have case names when the `induct` attribute was executed and hence the registered induction rule would not have any case names).